# Travis: E: Unable to locate package dotnet-sdk-2.0.0

Tags: .net-core, travis-ci

This morning my travis builds stopped with the error:

```
E: Unable to locate package dotnet-sdk-2.0.0
```

My travis yaml (below) hasn't changed from builds that were working:

```
language: csharp
dist: trusty
sudo: required
mono: none
dotnet: 2.0.0
solution: Dibware.Salon.sln
addons:
  sonarcloud:
    organization: "dibley1973-github" # the key of the org you chose at step #3
    token:
      secure: $SONAR_TOKEN
branches:
  only:
    - master
before_script:
  - chmod +x build.sh
  - chmod +x run-tests.sh
script:
  - ./build.sh
  - ./run-tests.sh
  - sonar-scanner
```

The key entries of the log is below:

```
C# support for Travis-CI is community maintained.
Please open any issues at https://travis-ci.community/c/languages/37-category and cc @joshua-anderson @akoeplinger @nterry
Installing .NET Core
$ export DOTNET_SKIP_FIRST_TIME_EXPERIENCE=1
$ export DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT=1
7.67s0.49sE: Unable to locate package dotnet-sdk-2.0.0
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'dotnet-sdk-2.0.0'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'dotnet-sdk-2.0.0'
The command "sudo apt-get install -qq dotnet-sdk-2.0.0" failed and exited with 100 during .
Your build has been stopped.
```

Link to travis builds:
https://travis-ci.com/dibley1973/Dibware.Salon

Any advice on why it was failed is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found this post here suggesting changing dist to `xenial`:

https://travis-ci.community/t/dotnet-core-2-2/1216

This seems to have fixed it